# Repeat dots in LESS / SASS for Content property

Tags: css, sass, less

Take a look at below CSS styles and I'm planning to use LESS & SASS for two different projects and is this possible:

```
.longDots {
  content: "  ......................................................................................................";
}

.shortDots {
  content: "....................";
}
```

I want to avoid repeated dots; to have it as single dot and that too should be configurable; to change it as `-, #, *`

Something `mixin` like below.

```
 .longDots {
    content: repeater('.', 25);
}

.shortDots {
    content: repeater('.', 10);
}

.longDashes {
    content: repeater('-', 25);
}

.shortDashes {
    content: repeater('-', 10);
}
```

Comment: Could at least please explain in which part my answer lacks? Even @blonfu himself stated that my answer was more complete and better. I don't want to steal credit from him, I only want to improve myself and therefor know if I missed a point or requirement you made? (I don't ask you to change the accepted answer, just to explain your choice.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do a mixin in SASS, in LESS I think you can do something similar. Some characthers like points or dashes must be between quotation marks.

**SASS**

```
@mixin repeat($character, $n){
  $c:"";
  @for $i from 1 through $n {
    $c: $c + $character;
 }
   content: $c;
}

.dash{
  @include repeat("-", 4)
}

.dot{
  @include repeat(".", 6)
}

.letter{
  @include repeat(x, 2)
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
.dash {
  content: "----";
}

.dot {
  content: "......";
}

.letter {
  content: "xx";
}
```

Or you can do also a function:

**SASS**

```
@function repeat($character, $n){
  $c:"";
  @for $i from 1 through $n {
    $c: $c + $character;
 }
    @return $c;
}

.dash{
  content: repeat("-", 4)
}

.dot{
  content: repeat(".", 6)
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
.dash {
  content: "----";
}

.dot {
  content: "......";
}
```

---

---

In LESS there isn't `for` sentences and I can't found a clean way to do but this code works (the output is quite dirty):

**LESS**

```
.repeat(@char, @i) when (@i> 0) {
   .repeat(@char, (@i - 1)); 
  content+_:"@{char}";
}

.dash {
  .repeat("-" ,3);
}

.dot {
  .repeat("." ,5);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
.dash {
  content: "-" "-" "-";
}
.dot {
  content: "." "." "." "." ".";
}
```

Comment: There is no option in LESS ?

Comment: I do also in  Less, the output is not very clean but works

Comment: Is a syntax mistake, missing space between `@i` and `-` .Corrected

Comment: content property should be out of mixin and content property value should have single open and close quotes.

Comment: @AlameluDilli Yes, I know but is the only solution I can found, look de Seika85 solution, he do better than me

Comment: i accept yours as answer but still looking for better one

Comment: Maybe the last update of the Seika85's answer is usefull for you. My function in SASS is correct and clean but  I'm not proud of the LESS mixin I do.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like:

**SASS**

```
@mixin repeater($item, $count) {
    $string: "";
    @for $i from 1 through $count {
        $string: $string + $item;
    }
    content: $string;
}

.longDots {
    @include repeater('.', 25);
}

.shortDots {
    @include repeater('.', 10);
}

.longDashes {
    @include repeater('-', 25);
}

.shortDashes {
    @include repeater('-', 10);
}
```

The mixin could also be written like:

```
@mixin repeater($item, $count) {
    $string: "";
    @for $i from 1 through $count {
        $string: str-insert($string, $item, $i - 1);
    }
    content: $string;
}
```

or:

```
@mixin repeater($item, $count) {
    $string: "";
    @while $count > 0 {
        $string: $string + $item;
        $count: $count - 1;
    }
    content: $string;
}
```

or:

```
@mixin repeater($item, $count) {
    $string: "";
    @while $count > 0 {
        $string: str-insert($string, $item, $count);
        $count: $count - 1;
    }
    content: $string;
}
```

Whatever appeals more to you.

You can always test your small parts of SASS online at e.g. http://sass.js.org/ or http://www.sassmeister.com/, if you don't have lokal tools for that.

---

For **LESS** you need a little bit more complex mixins:

```
.contentresult(@string, @count) when (@count = 1) {
    content: @string
}

.repeater(@item, @count, @string: "") when (@count > 0) {
    .repeater(@item, (@count - 1), "@{string}@{item}");
    .contentresult("@{string}@{item}", @count);
}

.longDots {
    .repeater('.', 25);
}

.shortDots {
    .repeater('.', 10);
}

.longDashes {
    .repeater('-', 25);
}

.shortDashes {
    .repeater('-', 10);
}
```

The first mixin is an if-statement, the second one is the actual loop. It's important to use these two separate mixins, because only the *repeater* mixin would produce a lot of `content` properties for each iteration with the shortest at the bottom unfortunately.

Tested with http://less2css.org/. *(It compiles successfully with LESS version 1.3.3 and later.)*

---

---

*Since OP updated his question:*

**SASS**

```
@function repeater($item, $count) {
    $string: "";
    @for $i from 1 through $count {
        $string: $string + $item;
    }
    @return "#{$string}";
}

.longDots {
    content: repeater('.', 25);
}
```

*With `"#{$string}"` I'm just showing you another way of accessing the content of a variable. You could also just use `$string`. Every mixin I showed you earlier is working once you turn it into a function the way I did here.*

**LESS**

```
.contentresult(@string, @count) when (@count = 1) {
    @return: @string
}

.repeater(@item, @count, @string: "") when (@count > 0) {
    .repeater(@item, (@count - 1), "@{string}@{item}");
    .contentresult("@{string}@{item}", @count);
}

.longDots {
    .repeater('.', 25);
    content: @return;
}
```

Comment: There is no option in LESS ?

Comment: @Seika85 good point your LESS solution, I wasn't able to concatenate the characters

Comment: Guys, updated my mistake in the question. i want the content property to be out of mixin, so that i can reuse it somewhere.

Comment: In SASS you can use a function, I have done in my answer

Comment: I updated my answer to have actual return values in both SASS and LESS. In LESS it's pretty ugly though, but the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

#### LESS

Based on [Seika85's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38715111/3217306), I've created a more generalized function for repeating an input arg with your choice of delimiter:

```
.repeater(@item, @count, @delimiter: " ", @iterated-item: "") when (@count = 1) {
  @return: ~'@{iterated-item}@{item}';
}
.repeater(@item, @count, @delimiter: " ", @iterated-item: "") when (@count > 1) {
  .repeater(@item, (@count - 1), @delimiter, ~'@{iterated-item}@{item}@{delimiter}');
}
```

Usage:

```
div {
  background-image: .repeater(url(foo.svg), 5, ", ")[];
}
```

Compiles to:

```
div {
  background-image: url(foo.svg), url(foo.svg), url(foo.svg), url(foo.svg), url(foo.svg);
}
```